# About looping through environment variables but looking for the first char in them

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wrote this code,

```
set /p Letter=Enter your FavoriteLetter:
if "%1" == "" (
   echo Usage: Enter Your Birth Date EX. (November)  
   exit /b 1
) 

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
```

What i would like to do is take the users letter that they entered and loop through all environment variables with a for loop, then return how many i found that start with the given letter they input. Please if you have the time do explain it to me i want to learn as well as find out the answer.

Comment: Do you mean "The environment variable starts with the selected letter" or "The environment variable's value starts with the selected letter"

Comment: The environment variable starts with the selected letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "$c=0"

set /p "$Answer=Enter a letter : "

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('set %$Answer% 2^>nul') do (
  set /a $c+=1
  echo No !$c! ==^> %%a
)

if !$c!==0 goto:error
exit/b

:error
Echo Env. Var. : %$Answer% ==^> Not Defined
```

Comment: Is there anyway you can explain to me whats going on in this?

Comment: With `set [Letter]` you'll get all the env. variables starting with `[letter]`. So you just have to loop on these variable with a `FOR loop`, incrementing a counter (`$c` in the example).

Comment: Alright, and what about adding error levels to this one for success and one for no success?

Comment: Check my Edit ! Just defining `set $c=0` and testing its value at the end you'll now if there is some occurence.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET /p "letter=Choose a letter "
IF NOT DEFINED letter GOTO :eof
SET "letter=%letter:~0,1%"
FOR /f %%a IN ('2^>nul set %letter% ^|find /c "=" ' ) DO SET count=%%a
ECHO %count% variables START "%letter%"
GOTO :EOF
```

- Input the letter
- Set the value of `letter` (if it's been defined) to the one character following the 0'th (ie. the first character only)
- execute `set` with an argument of that letter which lists all of the variables starting therewith. The `2>nul` suppresses errors.
- Pipe the output of the 'set' to `find` and count (`/c`) the lines that contain `=`.
- Assign the output to `count`
- Report